# Reactjs Router is causing Array to become undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I am trying to fetch JSON data from server running on another port in my pc using axios and renders it on homepage. I want to setup Router to components. But whenever I wrap `Router` around my components It causes Array `recipeslists` to become `undefined` (*see below console output*) and hence I can not `map` that Array in my `Allrecipes` Component But without any Router it works fine.

`App.js`'s code is as follows

```js
import React, { useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Allrecipes from './components/Allrecipes'
import Createrecipe from './components/Createrecipe'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
    const [recipeslists,setRecipes] = useState([])
    const [filterRecipe,setFilterRecipe] = useState([])
    const [search,setSearch] = useState('')
    console.log("in app")

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("useEffect")
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/recipes')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data
        })
        .then( recipeslist => {
            console.log(recipeslist,"recipes")
            setRecipes(recipeslist)
            setFilterRecipe(recipeslist)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    },[])

    function handlechange(event){
        var query = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
        setSearch(query)

        var filter_recipes = filterRecipe.filter((recipe) =>
            recipe.dish_name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
        )

        setRecipes(filter_recipes)
    }


    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <Navbar handlechange={handlechange}  search={search}/>
                <Allrecipes recipeslists={recipeslists} /> 
            </div>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Allrecipes} />
            <Route path="/recipes/create" exact component={Createrecipe} />
        </Router>
    )

}
export default App
```

`Allrecipes.js` code is as follow

```js
import React from "react"
import Recipe from './Recipe'

const Allrecipes = (props) => {
    const {recipeslists} = props
    console.log(recipeslists,"*** recipes array in Allrecipes***")

    return (
        <div className="recipecontainer">
               {recipeslists.map( recipeitem => <Recipe key={recipeitem.id} recipeitem={recipeitem} />)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Allrecipes
```

**Output** of above code in console:

[image]

**Output** in console without using Router:

[image]

Explain me,

- why Router is causing Array to become undefined? or it is another bug I am unknown of?
- If this is wrong implementation or method of using Router in Reactjs , then what is the correct way to do it?

Thank You. I would appreciate your any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `component` prop, pass the component as a child:

```js
<Route path="/" exact>
  <Allrecipes recipeslists={recipeslists} /> 
</Route>
```

That is the [recommended way](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) of rendering components in the route.

However, you could also use `render` if you'd like:

```js
<Route path="/" exact render={(routeProps) => {
  <Allrecipes recipeslists={recipeslists} {...routeProps} />
}} />
```

You just can't use the `component` prop because with that you're only passing a component *reference* (`Allrecipes`), not an *instance* (`<Allrecipes />`) of the component to which you can pass props.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, when you use the router you don't pass the list and your component get the list from the props. in your code it looks like that:

When you are **not** using the Router

```
<Allrecipes recipeslists={recipeslists} />
```

When you are using the Router

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Allrecipes} />
```

You should query the data inside your component and not get it as a prop.

Comment: thank you! since  Brian has explained correct way I am accepting his ans.

Comment: actually he gave a better solution that i didn't knew. i up voted his answer to